# attendant god -- what is it exactly?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Source: [UFO fanatics spot ancient god on Mars](http://www.cnet.com/news/ufo-fanatics-spot-ancient-god-on-mars/#ftag=YHF65cbda0)

Example:

> If you squint and let your imagination run wild, then you can see the resemblance to ancient sculptures like you might find in the British Museum. It especially echoes a Neo-Assyrian **attendant god** dedicated to Nabu, a god of wisdom.

What is an attendant god exactly?

Comment: An accompanying god, I guess, a kind of a second-tier god who accompanies or serves the main god.

Comment: I think @CopperKettle is right.  Here's an example of the usage of a similar phrase, **attendant deity**:  "Papsukkal is an attendant deity serving higher gods (usually Anu) as minister.  Attendant deities such as Papsukkal were invoked to intercede with the higher gods and goddesses on behalf of human supplicants. They guarded access to higher gods, thus functioning as gate-keepers."  (http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/amgg/listofdeities/papsukkal/)

Comment: I'm going to move this into an answer for the question, since it hasn't gotten any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An **attendant god** is a minor god who is an *attendant* to another god, meaning that he accompanies or serves another god.

Here's an example of the usage of a similar phrase, **attendant deity**: "Papsukkal is an attendant deity serving higher gods (usually Anu) as minister. Attendant deities such as Papsukkal were invoked to intercede with the higher gods and goddesses on behalf of human supplicants. They guarded access to higher gods, thus functioning as gate-keepers." (http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/amgg/listofdeities/papsukkal)